# Rails performances with both BaseController and APIController. Is APIController the same speed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

If I use Rails 5 with both server-rendered pages and API endpoints, the first inherited from BaseController and the second ones inheriting from APIController my Rails app is slower than a `new rails --api` only app for API endpoints?

Comment: An api only app shaves off quite a bit of stuff thats not needed like the sessions and cookies middleware. I don't think you will have a huge difference in response time but the memory signature for the api only app will likely be much smaller. So an API only app should be able to handle more requests with the same resources.

Comment: The best way to test it is probably just to setup both types of apps and run a benchmarking tool like [siege](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/11/benchmarking-and-load-testing-with-siege).